# $f$ is partially derivable if and only if $f$ is derivable in the direction of the standard unit vectors $e_{1},...,e_{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-derivative

$f$ is a function defined by, $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ with $U \subset \mathbb{R^{n}}$ open. **v** $\in \mathbb{R^{n}}$ a unitvector then we say that $f$ is derivatible in a point $a \in U$ in the direction of **v** if the function $t\to f(a+t$**v**) is derivatble in $zero$

I want to proof that $f$ is partially derivable if and only if $f$ is derivable in the direction of the standard unit vectors $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ with $e_{i}=(0,...,0,1,0,....,0)$ with $1$ at place $i$.

My definition of partial derivatble is:

If $U\subset \mathbb{R^{n}}$ open and $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ a function. We say that $f$ is partial derivatible in a point $(a_{1},...,a_{n}) \in U$ if for every $i:1,...,n$ the function $h_{i}: x\to f(a_{1},...,a_{i-1},x,a_{i+1},...,a_{n})$ is derivatible in $a_{i}$

I tried the following. Can someone check if it's correct and help me to understand my mistakes.

$=>$ $f$ is partial derivable. We need to prove that a function $t \to f(e_{i}+tv)$ is derivable in zero. $v$ is also a standard unit vector, with $v \in \mathbb{R^{n}}$. Let's call the previous function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then $g$'(t)=$f'(e_{i}+tv)v$. This exist beceause $f$ is partial derivative. Now $g'(0)=f'(e_{i})v$ which is also derivable beceause $f$ is partial derivative.

$<=$ if $f$ is derivative in all the directions of the standard unit vector, then we can write every other direction as a lineaire combination of the standard unit vectors. This implicate that $f$ will be partial derivative.

Comment: Is this true? What about the function which is $1$ on the axes and $0$ everywhere else?

Comment: This a theorem , so I assumed it is correct.

Comment: Well I think you haven't stated all the conditions of the theorem here. Does this question help at all: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646296/existence-of-partial-derivatives-implies-differentiability

Comment: no not really. I will try to rewrite my question

Comment: I really think i put everything in the question

Comment: Here's another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026114/why-does-continuous-partial-differentiability-imply-total-differentiability

Comment: thank you for trying to help, but i really want to understand why mine is incorrect then? The questions you send are proves of other questions, mine is using already proved theorems.

Comment: I have given you a counterexample, and questions which indicate the sort of conditions you need to get such a theorem.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. For $n \ge 2$, the following three conditions on a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are in strictly increasing order by strength, and in particular are *inequivalent*:

1. The partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ exist at $p$.
2. The directional derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ exist for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ at $p$.
3. $f$ is differentiable at $p$.

(I'm not sure whether by "partially derivable" you mean 2 or 3, but the statement is false either way.)

Your argument for $\Leftarrow$ does not work; you've just assumed that the partial derivative exists which is exactly what you were trying to prove. It is true that *if* $f$ is differentiable then every directional derivative is a linear combination of partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$, but you can't assume that here.

ancientmathematician's nice counterexample in the comments of the function $f$ which is equal to $1$ on the coordinate axes and $0$ otherwise shows that **1 does not imply 2** (which also shows that 1 does not imply 3); the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ exist at the origin and are equal to $0$, but the directional derivatives in all other directions fail to exist at the origin.

You can find a counterexample showing that **2 does not imply 3** at [this MO question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/show-that-fracx3x2y2-is-not-differentiable-at-0-0-even-though-al), namely the function

$$f(x, y) = 
  \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{for } (x,y)=(0,0) \\
   \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}       & \text{for } (x,y) \neq (0,0)
  \end{cases}$$

which is also a counterexample showing that "the directional derivatives exist for every $v$ at every point" does not imply "$f$ is differentiable at every point."

Comment: Your counterexample to "1 implies 2" doesn't work : your fonction doesn't have partial derivatives in the directions $e_1$ and $e_2$ at every point of the plane, which I guess is the hypothesis (not just having derivatives at 0).

Comment: @Paul: the OP doesn't specify whether they're asking for derivatives at every point or only talking about a specific point, and I specified that I was talking about a specific point. I agree that it would be nice to have a counterexample for all points also; do you know one?

Comment: why can't you assume that if f is differentiable (what you assume in <=) then every directional derivative ( who excists) is a lineair combination of partial derivatives. So they need to exist otherwhise f wouldn't be differentiable?

Comment: @questmath: I don't understand the question. In order to prove $\Leftarrow$ you need to prove that some directional derivative exists given only the hypothesis that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ exist, yes? This is false and your argument for it doesn't work because you've just assumed that the directional derivative exists. Please work through ancientmathematician's counterexample carefully to see why the directional derivatives don't exist in that case.

Comment: But isn't my question to prove that the partial derivates exist , if you know that the directional derivative exists? So I don't understand why you say that they don't exist because you assume they do.